# Why can we call reset on null shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

The `C++ primer` shows an example:

```
        auto &nos = result[word]; 
        if (!nos) nos.reset(new std::set<int>);
```

Where result is `std::map<string, shared_ptr<std::set<int>>>`.

My question is: if `!nos` holds, is `nos` null? then why can we call `reset` method on this null `shared_ptr`?

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "null `shared_ptr`". What do you think that means? Do you mean `std::shared_ptr<...>(nullptr)`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's null, in the *it doesn't point to any data* sense, but it's still a valid `shared_ptr` object. In the example code, you re-set it with a valid pointer.

Alternatively, you could write this:

```
auto &nos = result[word]; 
if (!nos) nos = std::make_shared<std::set<int>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Any smart pointer is a wrapper around a raw pointer. If you make things really simple, a smart pointer could look something like this:

```
template< class T >
class some_smart_ptr
{
public:
    <...>
    void reset(T * ptr)
    {
        delete _data; // possibly
        _data = ptr;
    }

    operator bool()
    {
        return _data == nullptr;
    }

    T * operator->()
    {
        return _data;
    }

    <...>

private:
    T * _data = nullptr;
};
```

As you can see it has an internal raw pointer to the data, and an overloaded `operator->` that is used to access it. The reset function takes ownership of the pointer that it gets as an argument, possibly deleting the object that has previously been stored at `_data` (e.g. for a shared pointer it happens when no other shared pointers point to the same `_data`).

If also has an overloaded `operator bool` so it can be used in conditions. In this case it just checks if the smart pointer is pointing to anything meaningful. As you can see, the `_data` being null does not prevent you from using the smart pointer itself.

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    void foo(){}
};

int main()
{
    some_smart_ptr<SomeClass> ptr; // ptr._data is nullptr
    ptr.reset(new SomeClass()); // here we are using the smart pointer object itself. 
    ptr->foo(); // here we are using the object that ptr points too. If ptr._data happened to be nullptr, you would have UB
}
```

Comment: I think the `reset` function should be written like this `some_smart_ptr<T>(ptr).swap(*this);`

Answer (score 1):

Basically *shared_ptr* has an [operator bool overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool).

So this is the check if *shared_ptr* stores the non null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
    auto &nos = result[word]; 
    if (!nos) nos.reset(new std::set<int>);
```

type of `nos` is `std::shared_ptr<std::set<int>>&`, hence `nos` is not null, and in fact can't be null.

`if (!nos)` will call `if (!nos.operator bool())` (see [std::shared_ptr::operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool)
), which is checking if `nos` hold a `nullptr` or not. If it hold `nullptr`, then reset it to a valid pointer.

Note, you can see that `nos.reset(new std::set<int>);` is a `member-of-object` operator, not a `member-of-pointer` operator. Refer to [Member access operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access)

In `std::shared_ptr`, the `member-of-pointer` operator is overrided with this implementation:

```
T * operator->()
{
    return /* the raw pointer */;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
result = std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<std::set<int>>>;
```

Then `operator[]()` on this line:

```
auto &nos = result[word];
```

gives us a reference to either

- (if `result` contains `word`) a reference to the existing shared pointer, or
- (if `result` does not contain `word`) a new, *default-constructed* shared pointer.

In the second case, the default-constructed shared pointer manages no object, and its `operator bool()` returns false.  This may be called an *empty* smart pointer.  In this case, the next line sets it to point to a newly constructed set, so that a subsequent `operator[]()` with the same argument will return a non-empty pointer:

```
if (!nos)
    nos.reset(new std::set<int>);
```

The action of the `reset()` method is:

1. If the pointer already owns an object, and is the last `shared_ptr` owning it, then delete it.  (We know from `if (!nos)` that this pointer does not already own an object, so nothing happens in this step).
2. Set the owned object to the supplied argument.  (In this case, that's the newly-constructed `std::set`.  It will be destroyed using `delete` when the last shared pointer to it is destroyed.)

---

A couple of notes on this code:

- It's not clear from the extract you've posted why the code needs the indirection of the shared pointer, rather than simply having `result` be a simple `std::map<std::string, std::set<int>>`.
- Creating an empty shared pointer and then resetting it to point to a new object may exhibit poorer data locality than creating a shared pointer with `std::make_shared()`, as there's no opportunity to combine allocation of the object and the pointer's control structure.